# How can I architect the following inheritance problem in Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following java classes.  These cannot be modified

```
class RealtimeData {
    protected void onEvent(Object obj) {
        ...
    }
}

class HistoricalData {
    protected void onEvent(Object obj) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In Scala, I have a BusinessLogic class which does not require recompilation when switching from historical to live data.  I have tried something like the following

```
trait Realtime extends RealtimeData {
    override def onEvent(obj: Any) {
        // my processing here
    }
}
```

then

```
new BusinessLogic with Realtime
```

With the idea being that I could also do

```
new BusinessLogic with Historical
```

Unfortunately I run into an inheritance compilation problem.  Are there alternative ways to achieve the overall goal of no recompilation of BusinessLogic?

Answer (score 0):

Could not `BusinessLogic` simply get a `Data` at construction. If `RealTimeData` and `HistoricalData` have no common ancestor (is *that* your problem?), then it is probably best to define the service used by `BusinessLogic` as a trait and add implicit conversions.

```
trait Data { def onEvent(obj: Any) }
object Data {
  implicit def fromRealTime(r: RealTimeData) = new Data{
    def onEvent(obj: Any) = r.onEvent(obj)
  // same for Historical
}

class BusinessLogic[D <% Data](data: D)
```

Alternatively, is what you want is to add behavior to your java data class, again implicit might be the way to go. Still with the trait `data`, the implicit conversions, and the parameter at constructor, you might add another implicit conversion

```
object BusinessLogic {
  implicit def extendedWithBusinessLogic[D <% Data](data: D) = new BusinessLogic(data)
}
```

Finally, you may also consider structural types, the closest think to what you tried, but I'm not sure to understand what for :

```
type Data = {def onEvent(obj: Any)}
trait BusinessLogic{self: Data => 
  def onSeveralEvents(objs: Any*) = for (obj <- objs) onEvent(obj)
}
val historicalWithBusiness = new HistoricalData with BusinessLogic
```